# Cakephp model becoming very big, looking for sensible way of breaking into several files

Tags: model-view-controller, model, cakephp-2.0

I am working on a project with a somewhat misused model file. It contains around 8000 lines of code, and is changed several times a day. Just imagine the horror of finding a specific change in the git version history.

The main structure (not at all very modellisch, I know) is a big case-structure. It contains some 5000 lines of code, and some 90 cases. As only one case is run on every page load, I imagine it would be convenient to just break it up into 90 different files. Would help tremendously for the git version history as every future change would belong to one of these 90 files instead of the big dump of code as today.

Anyone getting a good idea of how to do this? I was thinking about loading a Helper named smartly so I could kill the entire case-structure, but that's for views..

Just to give an idea of the structure:

```
switch($theMagicNumber)
{
  case 1:
    // Several hundred lines of code.
    break;
  case 2:
    ...repeat about 90 times.
}
```

Comment: I think you can brake your code into helpers, behaviors this is the benefit of Cakephp we can use opps concept by importing classes.

Comment: @Harendra, how can I use a helper inside a model? I normally use helpers in views, where they are perfect for this type of task.

Comment: this is not the perfect thing to use helper in model. but this type of task we can use helpers or any other classes. because cake used OOPS concept. we can Import any class with in any other by creating objects.